# Probability distribution similar to log-normal.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I just got some moments of a random variable that have the form as follows.

$E(X^n)=\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!}e^{n(n+1)x}$

It looks like a log-normal distribution, but not a log-normal distribution.
Is there a well-known probability distribution in which moments have the mentioned form?

Comment: To me they do not even look like the [moments of a lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments). Please elaborate.

Comment: If I ignore the former constant term and consider only the exponential term, the form of the moments have the form moment of the lognormal distribution. So I think it is concerned with lognormal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

When a lognormal variable is defined as
$$
Y=e^{\mu+\sigma Z}\,,\quad Z\sim N(0,1)
$$
then the [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments) of $Y$  are -as we know-
$$
\mathbb E[Y^n]=e^{\mu n +\frac{1}{2}n^2\sigma^2}\,.
$$
Therefore, with $\mu=x$ and $\sigma^2=2x$ we get
$$
\mathbb E[Y^n]=e^{n(n+n)x}\,.
$$
[Writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Related_sequences_and_functions)
$$
(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}
$$
we get
$$
\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!}=\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{2^n}{2n\choose{n}}\approx\frac{n!}{n^n}
$$
where we used that, for large $n$,
$$
{2n\choose n}\approx\frac{(2n)^n}{n!}
$$
[holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1458403/949989).