# Approximate combination $^nC_k$ by polynomial

Tags: polynomials, combinations, approximation

Is it possible to approximate ${}^n C _k$ by polynomial? I want only to know the order (e.g. $O(n^3)$), so accuracy doesn't matter much.

If $n \gg r$, we have
$$
{}^n C _r = O(n^r).
$$

But how about general case?

Comment: If $r$ is a constant, ${n\choose r}$ is a polynomial in $n$, of degree $r$. In the general case, it depends. Well, you may write ${n\choose r}=O(2^n)$, but it's not very useful.

Comment: $\binom{n}{1}=n$; $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$; $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}$; etc... do you want more than that ?

Comment: Even in the case $n \gg r$, what you write is wrong: if $r=\sqrt{n}$, you can't bound by a polynomial.

Comment: @JeanMarie For example, I sometimes want to know the order of ${}_{735} C _{214}$ without starting Python and typing `comb(735, 214)` to estimate complexity in competitive programming.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Approximation I want doesn't necessarily be very accurate. For example, ${}_{1000} C _3 = 1.7 \times 10^8 \simeq O(1000^3)$. This level of accuracy is enough.

Comment: Careful with $O$. What you write is nonsense, a constant is always $O(1)$. And you can't write either $\simeq O(n^3)$, either it's $O(n^3)$ or it's not. Big-$O$ has a precise definition: $f(x)=O(g(x))$ when $x\to x_0$ is there are constant $M$ and $m$ such that $|f(x)|<M\,|g(x)|$ for all $x>m$. Don't try to play around with this notation.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for pointing out it and sorry for my poor use of notation. Is it possible to quickly know the order of, for example, ${}_{735} C _{214}$ in mental arithmetic? Currently I always use Python, but it sometimes seems cumbersome to start Python only to calculate the value.

Comment: Not really. You can't rewrite $n\choose k$ with factorials and use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but you still need a calculator to find an approximation. Maybe an expert in mental arithmetic has tricks, but the only thing I can't tell you right away is it's less than $2^{735}$ (because $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}=2^n$). You might use the fact that [the binomial distribution has a bell shape](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176425/why-is-a-binomial-distribution-bell-shaped) to find a coarse approximation.

Comment: Typo: yu **can** rewrite, of course.

Comment: Just use Stirling's Approximation to as many orders as you need. The most naive version (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447296/stirlings-approximation-for-binomial-coefficient)) gives an approximation of $\frac{n^k}{k!}$, and more terms of Stirling will improve that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approximation comes, as usual, for Stirling apparoxiamtion.

Considering $k=a \,n$
$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{a n}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma ((1-a) n+1)\, \Gamma (a n+1)}$$ Taking logarithms, using three times Stirling approximation and finishing with Taylor series
$$\log \left (\binom{n}{a n}\right)=-\big[a\log(a)+(1-a)\log(1-a)\big]\,n-\log \left( \sqrt{2\pi a(1-a)  n}\right)-$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {P_k(a)}{c_k\,\big[a(1-a)n \big]^{2k+1}}$$ The $c_k$  form sequence $A046969$ in $OEIS$ and the very first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & P_k(a) \\
 0 & a^2-a+1 \\
 1 & -a^6+3 a^5-3 a^4+a^3-3 a^2+3 a-1 \\
 2 & a^{10}-5 a^9+10 a^8-10 a^7+5 a^6-a^5+5 a^4-10 a^3+10 a^2-5 a+1 \\
 \end{array}
\right)$$

For the case of  `comb(735, 214)` you used in comments, neglecting the summation gives for its logarithm $439.9103$ while its exact value is $439.9098$. The first term of the summation is $-0.0004$.

Answer (score 1):

This approximation is good for quick estimates:

$$ \left(\frac{n}{r}\right)^r \le \binom{n}{r} \le \left(\frac{e\cdot n}{r}\right)^r$$

(see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352338/proof-for-the-upper-bound-and-lower-bound-for-binomial-coefficients) for proof). If $r > \tfrac{n}{2}$, then use the identity $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$ first to get tighter bounds.

Using the example from your comment,

$$ 3^{214} < \left(\frac{735}{214}\right)^{214} \le \binom{735}{214} \le \left(\frac{2.72\times 735}{214}\right)^{214} < 10^{214}$$

so we can roughly estimate the value to be in the $10^{100}$ to $10^{200}$ range. (The actual value is about $1.123\times 10^{191}$.)